# How to select / active some thing or a div from other page by clicking a link redirection using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Actually when I click a link (page 1) and it will redirected to other page (page 2) and a element (a div) in that page (page 2) should select or active or perform any operation on that using jquery.

Comment: You can pass param in URL

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Example.3A_Linking_to_an_external_location) attribute of the `<a>` tag .

**MDN:**

> The **href** attribute indicates the link target, either a URL or a URL **fragment**. A URL **fragment** is a name preceded by a hash mark (**#**), which specifies an internal target location (an **ID**) within the current document.

**Example:**

```
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Example.3A_Linking_to_an_external_location">
    Link Name
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `hash`.

**- On page one:**

Link and give data:
`home.html?dosomething=fade&when=now`

**- On page two:**

Obtain the data:
`window.location.hash`

*(Optional)* Make the data invisible for the user:
`window.location.hash=""`